# URLFetch Max Deadline is Only 60 Seconds for TaskQueues

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, urlfetch, deadlines

> Problem:I am calling URLFetch with a deadline of 480 seconds from
>   within a TaskQueue, but it is timing out after only 60 seconds.

The original question was asked in [official group](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10470) more than year ago, but still unanswered.

Bug confirmed, but there is no technical support or developers of gae. Maybe they're here?

Comment: I remember seeing this on their issues page. That would be the place to go.

Answer (score 3):

While there is information on this old thread that suggests otherwise, I don't believe this is a bug that will be fixed (or that it is a bug). It's unfortunate that this issue has not been updated or closed.

A Urlfetch (regardless) of where you make it from within appengine world has a maximum deadline of 60 seconds.

Requests on front end instances within appengine also have a lifetime of a maximum of 60 seconds.

Requests within the context of the Taskqueue however, have a lifetime of up to 10 minutes. This however does not mean that you can make a Urlfetch made from within the taskqueue context exceed the 60 second deadline.

Comment: if that it is not a bug - then reasonable raise an exception when trying to set the timeout more than 60 seconds, regardless of the context. Need to fix documentation. This behavior confuses people.

Comment: I agree, I wish that Google was better at cleaning up / maintaining there public issue tracker.